# ArcTan expressed as a radian fraction?

Tags: output-formatting, trigonometry

This type of answer is what I'm looking for:

```
In[58]:= ArcTan @ 1
Out[58]=  π/4
```

This is what mathematica gives me:

```
In[59]:= ArcTan@2
Out[59]= ArcTan[2]
```

Is it possible to express `ArcTan` in terms of $\pi$? I understand some fractions would be hairy.

I am using `Mathematica 8`.

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: **no**, `ArcTan[2]` is not fraction of $\pi$. But this is more of a mathematics question than pertaining to *Mathematica*.

If you want to “check” that the result is not expressable as a fraction of $\pi$, you can check for the continued fraction reprentation of $\arctan(2)/\pi$, and see that it does not seem to converge:

```
Table[FromContinuedFraction@ContinuedFraction[ArcTan[2]/\[Pi], n], {n, 20}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this

```
HoldForm[Pi]  (1/Pi ArcTan@2.)
```

[image]

or if you want a nicer way

```
Rationalize /@ (HoldForm[Pi] N@(1/Pi ArcTan@Range[5]))
```

[image]

**Edit**

The latter method works well in cases when there is  a rational fraction of $\pi$ :

```
Rationalize /@ (HoldForm[Pi] N @ (1/Pi ArcTan @ { Sqrt[1 - 2/Sqrt[5]], 2 - Sqrt[3], 
                                                  1/Sqrt[3], Sqrt[3], 1}))
```

[image]
[image]

To sum up : Mathematica does what it should do, namely `ArcTan[2]` is not a rational fraction of $\pi$ and that's why it returns `ArcTan[2]` unlike in case  `ArcTan[1]`. The above method is to express `ArcTan[x]` in terms of a real multiple of $\pi$.

If you want to get back what you have evaluated you shoud use `ReleaseHold`, e.g.

```
Tan @ ReleaseHold @ %
```

[image]